Quartus reporting less processors in system than actual available number
I'm new to FPGA and I'm starting to learn it with Quartus Prime Lite 23.1std.
After seeing the warning
Warning (18236): Number of processors has not been specified which may cause overloading on shared machines.  Set the global assignment NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS in your QSF to an appropriate value for best performance.
I found answers here and here about how to solve this. Then, since nproc returns 8 in my system I added set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS 7 to my qsf file. It got rid of the initial warning but now I get:
Warning (20031): Parallel compilation is enabled for 7 processors, but there are only 4 processors in the system. Runtime may increase due to over usage of the processor space. 
This seems wrong to me, I'm used to compile several C projects with make and I definitely use more than 4 processing cores for that. On a quick google to see if quartus runs on a VM of some sort I found nothing.
What is happening here? How should I fix this warning?

Question is a support question about Quartus, not about electrical engineering.

What CPU is used in your system and is Hyper-Threading enabled? If Hyper-Threading is enabled, and Quartus looks at the number of physical cores that could explain "but there are only 4 processors in the system" Quartus message. nproc reports the number of logical cores when checked on a CPU with Hyper-Threading enabled.

Have you tried set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS ALL as suggested in the linked answer?

@ChesterGillon with lscpu: 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1135G7 @ 2.40GHz. It seems I actually have 4 cores with 2 threads enabled. Now that you mentioned hyperthreading I found a link of someone saying they noticed quartus doesn't seem to properly deal with hyperthreads: https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-Quartus-Prime-Software/Any-way-to-use-hyper-threading/m-p/24507 so it's a know bug! Thanks for the help :)

@ChesterGillon about set_global_assignment -name NUM_PARALLEL_PROCESSORS ALL yes, and it solved the problem. I was more concerned about learning more and understanding what was happening than just solving the problem though.

FWIW parallel processing for FPGAs usually does not make much of a difference for total build time.

As @ChesterGillon's comment prompted me to find out, it seems quartus has a hard time leveraging hyperthreading resources.
My system has indeed 4 cores, with 2 threads per core, so quartus is somehow detecting only the 4 physical cores. I found no answer from Altera/Intel about if that is a feature or a bug, though.
